# Does Anyone Know This Font?

Tags: typography, font-identification

I saw this font on a YouTube video and love it, would be perfect for something I am working on at the moment but no online services can work out what it is.

[image]

Online services have trouble with the detached areas and can't track them properly, I'm hoping someone here will be able to tell me what it is, or know of something very similar with those types of sleek, sharp cuts in.

Comment: Looking at this, I get the idea that those *triangles* (hint, hint) are artwork and not part of the font design itself. Fill them in and try those font services again.

Comment: Try checking it out on this handy tool: https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author of the video? They probably know what font is that.

Comment: The font is Reckoner. http://www.dafont.com/reckoner.font (can't put it in an answer because the thread is on hold...)